# Use View as root homepage handler

Tags: views, uri

In Drupal 7 I'm trying to accomplish the following:

`1) www.domain.com          =   ViewA (All posts)
3)  www.domain.com/muffins  =   ViewA (Posts tagged with "Muffin" taxonomy)
4)  www.domain.com/cookies  =   ViewA (Posts tagged with "Cookie" taxonomy)
5)  www.domain.com/...      =   ViewA (Posts tagged with ... taxonomy)`

I have a view, listing posts, with only one contextual Filter of "Category" (my vocabulary containing the required taxonomy), which works when tested in views.

I can set `ViewA` as the homepage, satisfying `1)` but subsequent pages `2),3),4)` are **not** handled by `ViewA`. Instead they return `page not found` as Drupal isn't aware that `ViewA` can handle the requests.

I know I can create a second page view `ViewB` with an additional url path segment like this:

`www.domain.com/recipe/muffins  =   ViewB (Posts tagged with "Muffin" taxonomy)`

But then all of my content has to live one "level" down under `/recipe` — which is not ideal.

Also, since the taxonomy grows as more recipes are added, hard-coding menu paths in a module is no a solution... or is it?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible without modification to Drupal core's routing. When you specify a Views page as the frontpage (e.g. **/frontpage** when you override the default Frontpage view), you're telling Drupal to route all www.example.com requests to that path (e.g. **www.example.com/frontpage**).

If you mandate that a required contextual filter (e.g. **/frontpage/%**), that path component isn't "copied over" (e.g. **www.example.com/cookies** doesn't route to **www.example.com/fronpage/cookies**). Nor can you add a views page with the root path **/**. If this was possible, you'd then have to deal with the problem of overlapping paths (e.g. should **/admin** be handled by [`system_admin_menu_block_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.admin.inc/function/system_admin_menu_block_page/7.x) or by your view?).

Instead of trying to fight Drupal's routing system, you'd be better off trying to hook into the alias system. For example, a module invocating `hook_taxonomy_term_insert()`/`hook_taxonomy_term_update()` could add a new alias for each term item you wish to shortcut to your view (e.g. aliasing **/cookies** to **/frontpage/cookies**).